# DigitalPersona U.are.U java SDK doesnt answer without GUI

Tags: java, digital-persona-sdk

I'm currently developping a JAVA program which uses Digital Persona 4500.[DigitalPersonaBiometricSDKforWindows_3.4.0]

We're facing problems with it, the sample code uses a GUI that you can sample digital, it works fine with the GUI.

But if we dont use the GUI, the code stops on `Reader.Capture()`... I've tried many things like another Thread only for sampling and etc.

```
ReaderCollection m_coll = UareUGlobal.GetReaderCollection();
m_coll.GetReaders();
Reader m_reader = m_coll.get(0);
m_reader.Open(Reader.Priority.COOPERATIVE);
Reader.CaptureResult cr = m_reader.Capture(Fid.Format.ANSI_381_2004, Reader.ImageProcessing.IMG_PROC_DEFAULT, m_reader.GetCapabilities().resolutions[0], -1);
System.out.println(cr.quality);
```

Similar Question: [Call to Reader.Capture() in DigitalPersona U.are.U SDK does not return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67808136/call-to-reader-capture-in-digitalpersona-u-are-u-sdk-does-not-return)

Comment: Hey @Budelon. Can you tell me how/where you obtained the U are U Java SDK?

Answer (score 0):

I have just added solution in below question,

[Call to Reader.Capture() in DigitalPersona U.are.U SDK does not return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67808136/call-to-reader-capture-in-digitalpersona-u-are-u-sdk-does-not-return/70896458#70896458)

Copying same answer here,

I faced the similar issue and it can be fixed by opening a reader in exclusive mode as below,

```
m_reader.Open(Reader.Priority.EXCLUSIVE);
```

Refer to below lines from documents,

public static final Reader.Priority COOPERATIVE

Client uses this priority to open reader in cooperative mode. Multiple clients with this priority are allowed. Client receives captured images if it has window with focus.

public static final Reader.Priority EXCLUSIVE

Client uses this priority to open reader exclusively. Only one client with this priority is allowed.

Comment: Thank you I will try it, and let you know once it succeed

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.
SDK for digital persona finger print scanner for java (Android).
Its provide you bitmap. you can implement as a your requirment.
Check this android app download it, available on google  play store.
App Link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.digitalpersona.digitalpersona

For More Infomation Visite Offical Website of (Brain Wave App Studio)
http://digital.persona.sdk.android.brainwaveappstudio.com

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).